# How to reuse code in Python and Django

Tags: python, django, dry

I have a working revision/archiving system for Django that is present in multiple views. However I would like to re-write this whilst trying to adhere to the DRY principle.

#### Current Code

```
def archive_calc(self, rev_num, primary_field):
    model_a = InstrumentAnnual.objects.get(instrument_details_id = primary_field, revision_number = rev_num)
    model_b = InstrumentAnnualArchive()
    
    object_list_annual = model_a.instrumentperiodicreview_set.filter(instrument_annual__instrument_details = primary_field)
    object_list_ageing = model_a.instrumentequipmentitem_set.filter(instrument_annual__instrument_details = primary_field)
    
    for obj in object_list_annual:
        obj.instrument_annual_id = self.object.id
        obj.save()
    for obj in object_list_ageing:
        obj.instrument_annual_id = self.object.id
        obj.save()
    
    for field in model_a._meta.fields:
        setattr(model_b, field.name, getattr(model_a, field.name))
    model_b.pk = None
    model_b.current_revision = False
    model_b.save()
    
    model_a.delete()
```

*This part of the code is passed a rev number and primary key and archives the record using those objects*

#### Potential Solution

I have done quite alot of reading/Youtube watching and am a little unsure of the best path to take. Should I create a new app with something like this below in the view (of the newly created app) and then import the code into the desired view?

```
def archive_calc(self, rev_num, primary_field, type):
    if type == "instrument":
        model_a = InstrumentAnnual.objects.get(instrument_annual_id = primary_field, revision_number = rev_num)
        model_b = InstrumentAnnualArchive()
    
        object_list_annual = model_a.instrumentperiodicreview_set.filter(instrument_annual__instrument_details = primary_field)
        object_list_ageing = model_a.instrumentequipmentitem_set.filter(instrument_annual__instrument_details = primary_field)
    
        for obj in object_list_annual:
            obj.instrument_annual_id = self.object.id
            obj.save()
        for obj in object_list_ageing:
            obj.instrument_annual_id = self.object.id
            obj.save()

    elif type == "time":
        model_a = Time.objects.get(time_id = primary_field, revision_number = rev_num)
        model_b = TimeArchive()
        etc etc....
    
    for field in model_a._meta.fields:
        setattr(model_b, field.name, getattr(model_a, field.name))
    model_b.pk = None
    model_b.current_revision = False
    model_b.save()
    
    model_a.delete()
```

And then create an instance of 'archive_calc' using something like this in whatever view I need to use the archiving code?

```
from resusablecode.views import archive_calc

class InstrumentCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    (normal view code...)

    archiveinstance = archive_calc()
    archiveinstance(rev_num, primary_field, type)
```

*Would this work or am I way off the mark?*

Or is it best to stick with the current setup given the number of differences in each view?

Thanks in advance and just to clarify I am using class based views if that has any bearing on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Move as much logic from your view into your model classes. Follow the advice "skinny view, fat model".

I can recommend you the book "Two Scoops of Django" for best practices.

Example:

```
class InstrumentAnnual(models.Model):
    ...
    def archive_calc(self, rev_num):
        archive = InstrumentAnnualArchive()
        list_annual = self.instrumentperiodicreview_set.filter(...)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, buying a copy now! :)